# copy only the files in a directory

Tags: shell

I have 2 directories

```
       dir1/results1/a.xml
       dir1/results1/b.txt
```

and

```
      dir2/results2/c.xml
      dir2/results2/d.txt
```

I want to copy only the files in dir2/results2 folder into dir1/results1 folder so that the result is like this:

```
         dir1/results1/a.xml
         dir1/results1/b.txt
         dir1/results1/c.xml
         dir1/results1/d.txt
```

I tried shell comand

```
         cp -R dir2/results2/ dir1/results1/
```

but it is getting copied as

```
          dir1/results1/a.xml
          dir1/results1/b.txt
          dir1/results1/results2
```

what is the right way to do it?

Comment: `cp dir2/results2/*.* dir1/results1/` will skip results2

Answer (score 2):

In your concrete case,

```
cp dir/results2/* dir/results1
```

would do what you want. It would not work well in two cases:

- If you have files starting with a period, for instance *dir/results2/.abc*. These files would not be copied.
- If you have subdirectories in dir/results2. While they indeed would not be copied (as you required, because you want to copy only files, not directories), you would get an error message, which is at least not elegant.

There are solutions to both problems, so if this is an issue for you, create a separate post with the respective topic.

(UPDATE) If the filename expansion would generate an argument line which is longer as the allowed minimum (for instance, if there are many files in the directory, or those with long lines), my solution would not work either. In this case, something like

```
find dir/results2 -maxdepth 1  -type f | xargs -i --no-run-if-empty] cp {} dir/results1
```

This would also solve the problems with the hidden files, which I have mentioned above.

Comment: You may want to just discuss the use of the `-r` or `-a` option in your second case for completeness if the subdirectory copy is also wanted.

Comment: Note that if there is a great number of files in the `dir/results2/` directory the `cp` command will fail with `Too Many Argument` error message.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin : I was considering this, but felt that in this case, it would be too much. Actually, the OP seems to know the -r flag (since he used the equivalent -R), and since he explicitly said that he wanted to copy only files, I decieded to just mention the problem with contained directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
(cd dir1 && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | tar -T - --null -cf - ) | (cd dir2 && tar -xf -)
```

Handles all cases including . files and very large files but won't copy sibdirs. Remove the -depth to copy sibdirs. Requires gnutar.

Comment: @Johua : What is the advantage of squeezing the files through `tar` instead of copying them directly (using, say, `cp` or `rsync`)?

Comment: @user1934428: This preserves file attributes, etc. and will run in parallel if the two directories are on different disks.

Answer (score -1):

`tar`command is very handy for that.

Give this a try:

```
tar cf - -C dir2/results2 . | ( cd dir1/results1 ; tar xf - )
```

It will not only copy plain files but also any other ones found into `dir2/results2`, such as directories etc.

Comment: I think this question calls for excluding subdirs.